# Flagging menu on .downvoted-answer comments is broken

Tags: bug, design

I noticed a problem when flagging a comment on [this GraphicDesign comment](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27740/setting-up-responsive-grids-in-photoshop/27744#comment36466_27744) but confirmed it on [this SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614023/how-to-create-temp-table-from-a-dynamic-query/15614189#comment41071160_15614189).

When an answer is `.downvoted-answer`, the comment flagging menu is partially transparent like the whole rest of the answer. It also gets placed beneath the answer text input field.

This is because an opacity other than 1 [creates its own stacking context](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/).

[image]

Can we get this fixed please?

This issue still occurs on 9/20/15